# Simple Java game using grid

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

This picture is edited with photoshop to show what I want to do:

[image]

Basically, what I want to do is to move the black-stick-man by clicking on it and move to available positions(gray boxes).

This is what I've done so far:
Arena.java

```
public class Arena extends JFrame{
JPanel a = new JPanel();
Player players[][] = new Player[10][10];
private ImageIcon player = new ImageIcon("player.jpg");
private ImageIcon player2 = new ImageIcon("player2.jpg");
private ImageIcon poop = new ImageIcon("poop.jpg");
private ImageIcon moves = new ImageIcon("moves.jpg");

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Arena();
}

public Arena(){
    setTitle("The Arena");
    setSize(500,500);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    a.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            players[i][j] = new Player();
            a.add(players[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //player position
    players[9][4].setIcon(player);
    //player 2 position
    players[9][7].setIcon(player2);
    //poop
    players[7][2].setIcon(poop);
    players[5][7].setIcon(poop);

    add(a);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Player.java

```
public class Player extends JButton{
private int xPos;
private int yPos;

public Player(){

}

public int getXPos(){
    return xPos;
}
public int getYPos(){
    return yPos;
}
public void setXPos(){
    this.xPos = x;
}
public void setYPos(){
    this.yPos = y;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add a field to the `Player` class that tells you which player (or obstacle) it is? I'm sorry, I may not have understood what the problem is.

Comment: Basically I want to move the black stick man around by clicking on it and move it to my desire positions(gray boxes). But I don't know how to do it because all I did is just setting an icon to players[9][4]. How do I know players[9][4] is the black stick man? and how do I update its position? Do I create an object specifically for the black stick man?

Comment: That's not really a question though. Are you asking how to interact with mouse clicks?

Comment: I want to know how Do I know players[9][4] is the black stick man, because all I did is just setting an icon to that position.

Comment: Add an image field to your player class, use that player instance throughout your code, referencing the image when you need to display it

Comment: Could you give a simple code example?